# Put Value in a New Line Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table and in my  code on my html.erb file,

```
<td class="pstn-column"><%= a.lenders.pluck(:code).join(", ") %></td>
```

This returns the result in this format

```
Lender1, Lender2, Lender3
```

How do i make the result to look like this on the table

```
Lender1
Lender2
Lender3
```

I am using rails

Any help appreciated

Comment: `<td class="pstn-column"><%= a.lenders.pluck(:code).join("\n") %></td>`

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this
This code will add `br` tag after each element

```
 <td class="pstn-column"><%= a.lenders.pluck(:code).join('<br />').html_safe %></td>
```

or, this will add newline character after each element

```
<td class="pstn-column"><%= a.lenders.pluck(:code).join("\n") %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% a.lenders.pluck(:code).each do |lender| -%>
    <td class="pstn-column"><%= lender %></td>
<% end -%>
```

I assumed that you need each element in a separate cell.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new partial and pass the collection to the renderer.

_lender.html.erb

```
<tr><td><%= lender %></td></tr>
```

view.html.erb

```
<%= render @lenders %>
# Or
<%= render partial: 'lender', collection: @lenders %>
```

controller.rb

```
@lenders = a.lenders.pluck(:code)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a list of lenders, since that seems to resemble the result you are trying to achieve

```
<td>
  <ul>
    <% a.lenders.pluck(:code).each do |lender_code| %>
      <li><%= lender_code %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</td>
```

If you want to, the bullets can be removed trough CSS, using `<ul style='list-style: none;'>`